# How do I detect when the delete key has been pressed with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Pressing Enter is successful, but undo doesn't work.
My goal is to detect when the backspace key is pressed and try to delete the previous tag. But it does not detect the backspace printing.
Backspace key's ASCII code appears as 08.
https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/backspace-ascii-code-8.html
Where am I going wrong?

```js
$(".tag-input").on("keypress",function(event){

    //Not Working
    if(event.key === "Backspace" || event.key === "Delete"){
      alert("Detected backspace");
    }
    //Not Working
    if(event.which == 8){
      alert("Detected backspace");
    }
    
    //Working
    if(event.which == 13){
      alert("Detected Enter");
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="tag-input"/>
```

Comment: Try console.log(event); to find out the correct key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personaly i use “keypress” for printable characters.
“keydown” and “keyup” will capture all characters

so you could use keyup or keydown:

```
$(".tag-input").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        alert('Delete key pressed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help